# Relation between the stability of numerical integration and the stability of solution of system of equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-calculus

Consider the system of ODE $$\displaystyle \frac{d \bf u}{dt}=A {\bf u} ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(a)$$ formed as a result of a particular discretization say $D_1$ on a linear PDE  $$L u(t,x)=0$$ We see that the numerical integration by a particular discretization say $D_2$ on $(a)$ is stable if the eigen values of a matrix $A$ lies in the stability region of $D_2$.

But I couldn't connect the stability of solution for $(a)$ with the stability region of time integration $D_2$. How the time integration $D_2$ become stable if the eigen values of $A$ lies in the stability region of $D_2$, and how it is related with the stability of solution for the system of linear ODE system $(a)$ ?

Comment: The space discretization leads to eigenvalues of the order $\lambda\sim\Delta x^{-d}$ if $d$ is the order of the differential operator in space direction. Assuming these eigenvalues are negative, for explicit RK methods you need something like $|\lambda|\Delta t\le 1$, the right side could be as large as $2.5$, but the left side has also some coefficient in $\lambda=c\Delta x^{-d}$. So in total you get some condition $\Delta t\le M·\Delta x^d$.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "stability of the solution"? That it remains bounded in forward time, that it converges to some equilibrium, something else? If the PDE has solution that increase exponentially, then the discretized equation tends to do the same, and discussions of stability become meaningless, only the relative error of the integration methods matters in determining the step size.

Comment: I used ''stability of solution for the system $(a)$'' in an arbitrary sense of stability of system itself. Is there any correction ? and what do you mean by ''right side'' and ''leftside'' in your comments? I am not fully caught the concept. I request you to kindly provide a clarification.

Comment: From your discretized formulation it appears as if the PDE has to be of the form $\partial_tu=p(x,\partial_x)u$, with $p$ polynomial in the second argument. Possibly with $u$ vector valued, so that transformation into systems of first order in $t$ are included. Do you consider PDE that are not that nicely separated?

Comment: Sir, I am taking a linear parabolic PDE, and after a particular spacial discretization $D_1$, I got the system $(a)$, Now I've to apply $D_2$ (something like BDF-2 or Generalized Trapezoidal Formulas) on $(a)$. For the stability analysis, I need to check whether the eigen values of $A$ lies in the stability region of the linear multistep method $D_2$. Actually I want the reasoning behind the eigenvalue approach.

Comment: Are you asking why the basis change to the eigen-basis of $A$ decomposes the system into a set of uncoupled scalar equations $v_k'(t)=\lambda_kv_k(t)$?

Comment: Sir, Is it true that the numerical integration $D_2$ of $(a)$ is stable if the eigen values of $A$ lies in the stability region of the discretization $D_2$ ?

Comment: It is always the product $z=\lambda \Delta t$ that has to lie in the stability region. For the most relevant frequency components aka eigenvectors the eigenvalues are small and thus the product well within the stability region. For the rapidly oscillating components with correspondingly large eigenvalue the product has to be inside the stability region, else their coefficient rapidly increases from barely noticeable to very large.

Comment: So, Can we see the full discretization is stable from the stability of numerical integration $D_2$ ?